# How to find value of a 2-d array then add to an array depending on the value of 2-d array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, onchange, selectedindex

I'm having Trouble trying to add a value to a counter of a character object depending on the value in the 2-d array of characters.  There are multiple characters and I'm trying to find which character has the biggest counter.

```
function pushA() {
    for(var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
```

characters is a 2-d array the has might have a value of 1 in an index depending on the selectedindex of html code

```
        if(characters[i].value === 1){
```

if statement finds which index of 2-d array has a value of 1 and pushes a value to counter

```
            characters[i].counter.push(1);          
        }
        else{}
    }
    }

    pushA();
```

The counter is not being added to.

Comment: @Barmar my updated code

Comment: After spending a few minutes reading and re-reading through your question, i'm still not clear what you're asking. I'm not going to downvote you like others will because you've clearly put effort into this, but I need more clarification.

Comment: Thank you @PatrickMotard I'm new at javascript. I'm trying to assign the user to a tv character based on their answers to my questions.  I take their selected answer out of 5 questions and add a value to the character's array the user compares too. I then find the character with the longest array, to determine which character the user is like.  I'm having trouble creating the pushA function, to add a value to a characters array in the array of objects called characters, depending on which index has a value of one in the 2-d array above the .onchange function.

Comment: I feel like you're giving more information than is need, and it's obfuscating the real problem. Most of the information is just noise to me. Your problem is your pushA function. The most helpful way you can ask the question would be to provide the functions code, the inputs, the expected output, the error it's throwing, and any steps you've done on your own to solve the issue.

Comment: Does my answer to your question solve the issue for you? If not let me know and i'll revise it.

Comment: did you find any solutions? @PatrickMotard

Comment: Sorry @gpinson could you please show me what a character object looks like?